# Extern template with variadic arguments doesn't compile

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I try to create a extern template with variadic arguments like:

```
extern template<typename... XS> void log( XS... xs );
```

But gcc 7.2 doesn't compile it, and show the error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

I check the gcc status in c++11, and extern templates should work, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `extern` keyword does something different than you expect - if I understand correctly what you expect, of course.

The `extern` keyword is applied to *explicit instantiations* of a template, and it prevents the compiler from generating implicitly the code for that template while processing a certain translation unit. Per Paragraph 14.7.2/2 of the C++11 Standard:

> There are two forms of explicit instantiation: an explicit instantiation definition and an explicit instantiation
>   declaration. **An explicit instantiation declaration begins with the `extern` keyword**.

Without the `extern` keyword, the compiler would generate code for (say) `log(double, int)` in each translation unit that contains calls to `log(double, int)`, and this code - which would and should be identical for all translation units - would be eventually merged by the linker (the linker would basically discard all duplicates and keep only one).

The `extern` keyword saves you from this waste of compilation time by telling the compiler: "*Trust me, somebody else will instantiate this template somewhere else - you don't need to do it now*". **But that promise must be fulfilled**.

So for instance, if you have this primary template:

```
template<typename... Xs> void log(Xs... xs);
```

And you declare this explicit instantiation:

```
extern template void log(int, double);
```

Than you must have a corresponding explicit instantiation in some translation unit:

```
template void log(int, double)
```

Otherwise, the compiler will never ever produce code for `log<int, double>(int, double)`, and the linker will complain about undefined references.

Comment: Yes, you get it rigth. My intetion was to declare extern in a header and then the definition in a .cpp file. I see it's not allowed because it should have explicit parameters.

Comment: @Zhen: Yes, unfortunately the only situation where you are allowed to put template definitions in a `.cpp` file is when you create an explicit instantiation for all the template instantiations that would be otherwise generated implicitly. C++03 had a keyword called `export` that was meant to solve this problem, but it proved to be too hard for compiler vendors to support it (only EDG-based compilers did), so it got removed in C++11

Comment: @AndyProwl - and after implementing it, it was EDG who proposed removing it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: They deserve SO's "Unsung hero" gold badge :)